# Set Logo doesn't show logo on android Firebase UI

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebaseui

I've followed the official documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui) in using firebasebase UI but for some strange reason, the logo doesn't appear. Here is a sample of the Code.

```
   val providers = listOf(AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().build())

    listener = FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener{ firebaseAuth ->
        val user = firebaseAuth.currentUser
        if (user != null) {
            startActivity(Intent(this,  MainActivity::class.java))
            finish()
        } else {
            startActivityForResult(AuthUI.getInstance()
                    .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                    .setLogo(R.drawable.bus_logo)
                    .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                    .build(), RC_SIGN)
        }
    }
}
```

This is what am getting
[image]

Comment: Is you else part event riggered?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes, please. Everything works. Just that I don't see the logo even though I've set it in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logo only appears when the authentication provider selection screen is displayed. Since the app is currently configured to use only one provider (phone), this screen is not used. The logo will become visible when more than one provider are available for selection.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!